# Postgres Command in UserData for CloudFormation

Tags: postgresql, aws-cloudformation

I have a postgres server starting up on my server for a cloud formation template. The issue is that I am not sure how to have it load a file during runtime, what the proper user or command would be:

I've tried this:

```
May  2 13:50:16 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: 2016-05-02 13:50:16 (31.1 MB/s) - ‘psqlCloudera.sql’ saved [876/876]
May  2 13:50:16 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: psql -U postgres -a -f psqlCloudera.sql
May  2 13:50:16 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

And a bit different like this:

It involves a "su - postgres \n", in my userdata.

```
May  2 13:31:05 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: Saving to: ‘psqlCloudera.sql’
May  2 13:31:05 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: 0K                                                       100% 36.2M=0s
May  2 13:31:05 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: 2016-05-02 13:31:05 (36.2 MB/s) - ‘psqlCloudera.sql’ saved [876/876]
May  2 13:31:05 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: psql -a -f psqlCloudera.sql
May  2 13:31:05 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

What is the proper way to load in a postgres at startup?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the first bit of code works as long as you edit the pg_hba.conf and make it so you trust the local connections so you do not need to authenticate via the postgres user during the runtime of the cloud formation. The second option will not work because in CF apparently when you switch to a different user you need to chain commands together otherwise CF notices that the user has nothing to do and exits that user.